# I have 10 inputs, I need their values in another input when clicked, but returns [object Object]

Tags: jquery, click, each

```
var valor = $('.numbers input').each(function(){$('.numbers input').val();});
$(valor).click(function(){
    $('input#icms').val(valor);
});




<div class="numbers">
    <input type="button" id="number0" value="0">
    <input type="button" id="number1" value="1">
    <input type="button" id="number2" value="2">
    <input type="button" id="number3" value="3">
    <input type="button" id="number4" value="4">
    <input type="button" id="number5" value="5">
    <input type="button" id="number6" value="6">
    <input type="button" id="number7" value="7">
    <input type="button" id="number8" value="8">
    <input type="button" id="number9" value="9">
    <input type="button" id="point" value=".">

</div>

 <input type="text" class="calc" id="icms" value="" placeholder="CUSTO + ICMS">
```

I'll use the input above to receive the values from the input[type=button]. 
Console.log() shows me all the values, but not working as expected

Comment: What do you expect from this line: `var valor = $('.numbers input').each(function(){$('.numbers input').val();});`? Or in other words: this line doesn't make much sense and definitely does not what you want it to do.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach click event on each input type button. Then append value of clicked button to input using `this` keyword.

```js
$('.numbers input').click(function(){
    $('input#icms').val($('input#icms').val()+$(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numbers">
<input type="button" id="number0" value="0">
<input type="button" id="number1" value="1">
<input type="button" id="number2" value="2">
<input type="button" id="number3" value="3">
<input type="button" id="number4" value="4">
<input type="button" id="number5" value="5">
<input type="button" id="number6" value="6">
<input type="button" id="number7" value="7">
<input type="button" id="number8" value="8">
<input type="button" id="number9" value="9">
<input type="button" id="point" value=".">

</div>

 <input type="text" class="calc" id="icms" value="" placeholder="CUSTO + ICMS">
```

---

You was changed value of input to jQuery Object returned by `$('selector')`. That's why you got `[Object object]` in input. Also look at [`$().each(fn)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)